# Editing TextView outside the UI Thread

Tags: java, android

I have the below code:

```
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        pos = Calculo.Calcular();
                        mostrarFrases(pos);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

where mostrarFrases is:

```
void mostrarFrases(int pos){

    Mostrar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Texto);
    Mostrar.setText(Frases[pos*2+1], 0, Frases[pos*2+1].length);
}
```

It works if i haven't any thread but without it does not work. I need thread because i need to wait until Calculo.Calcular() finish its work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rule:** You cannot manipulate UI elements outside the UI thread.

Here is the proper way to do things:

```
//Asuming that your activiy is named MainActivity

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    pos = Calculo.Calcular();
                    //Manipulate your UI elements as following
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mostrarFrases(pos);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to touch Views on any thread other than the UI thread.

To solve this, try the following:

```
void mostrarFrases(final int pos){

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Mostrar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Texto);
        Mostrar.setText(Frases[pos*2+1], 0, Frases[pos*2+1].length);
     }});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not manipulate UI elements on any thread except the main UI thread.

So, in your case you got two choices: either use `runOnUIThread(Runnable)`, or use `AsyncTask` and do UI manipulations in `onPostExecute()`.

I'd go with `AsyncTask` - it is intended for this kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

UI manipulation must be done in main/ui thread. You have two options for this case:

- You have a reference to your Activity object.

  ```
  myActivity.runOnUiThread(...);
  ```
- Bind a handler to the main thread and:

  ```
  // Main thread
  Handler handler = new Handler();

  // Another thread
  handler.post(new Runnable(){...});
  ```